# Ray tune fail to start to run

Tags: python, ray

I just run a python script as is shown on https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/tutorials/tune-pytorch-cifar.html

However, when runing the script, it seems that no change happened for a long time. When Interrupting it with ctrl+c, it shows below.
I have no idea what have happened and what to do.

**The script**

```py
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import random_split
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from ray import tune
from ray.tune import CLIReporter
from ray.tune.schedulers import ASHAScheduler


def load_data(data_dir="./data"):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])

    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)

    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root=data_dir, train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

    return trainset, testset

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, l1=120, l2=84):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, l1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(l1, l2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(l2, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

def train_cifar(config, checkpoint_dir=None, data_dir=None):
    net = Net(config["l1"], config["l2"])

    device = "cpu"
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = "cuda:0"
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            net = nn.DataParallel(net)
    net.to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=config["lr"], momentum=0.9)

    if checkpoint_dir:
        model_state, optimizer_state = torch.load(
            os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "checkpoint"))
        net.load_state_dict(model_state)
        optimizer.load_state_dict(optimizer_state)

    trainset, testset = load_data(data_dir)

    test_abs = int(len(trainset) * 0.8)
    train_subset, val_subset = random_split(
        trainset, [test_abs, len(trainset) - test_abs])

    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_subset,
        batch_size=int(config["batch_size"]),
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=8)
    valloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        val_subset,
        batch_size=int(config["batch_size"]),
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=8)

    for epoch in range(10):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        epoch_steps = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_steps += 1
            if i % 2000 == 1999:  # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print("[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f" % (epoch + 1, i + 1,
                                                running_loss / epoch_steps))
                running_loss = 0.0

        # Validation loss
        val_loss = 0.0
        val_steps = 0
        total = 0
        correct = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(valloader, 0):
            with torch.no_grad():
                inputs, labels = data
                inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

                outputs = net(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                val_loss += loss.cpu().numpy()
                val_steps += 1

        with tune.checkpoint_dir(epoch) as checkpoint_dir:
            path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "checkpoint")
            torch.save((net.state_dict(), optimizer.state_dict()), path)

        tune.report(loss=(val_loss / val_steps), accuracy=correct / total)
    print("Finished Training")

def test_accuracy(net, device="cpu"):
    trainset, testset = load_data()

    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        testset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in testloader:
            images, labels = data
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = net(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    return correct / total


def main(num_samples=10, max_num_epochs=10, gpus_per_trial=2):
    data_dir = os.path.abspath("./data")
    load_data(data_dir)
    config = {
        "l1": tune.sample_from(lambda _: 2 ** np.random.randint(2, 9)),
        "l2": tune.sample_from(lambda _: 2 ** np.random.randint(2, 9)),
        "lr": tune.loguniform(1e-4, 1e-1),
        "batch_size": tune.choice([2, 4, 8, 16])
    }
    scheduler = ASHAScheduler(
        metric="loss",
        mode="min",
        max_t=max_num_epochs,
        grace_period=1,
        reduction_factor=2)
    reporter = CLIReporter(
        # parameter_columns=["l1", "l2", "lr", "batch_size"],
        metric_columns=["loss", "accuracy", "training_iteration"])
    result = tune.run(
        partial(train_cifar, data_dir=data_dir),
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 2, "gpu": gpus_per_trial},
        config=config,
        num_samples=num_samples,
        scheduler=scheduler,
        progress_reporter=reporter)

    best_trial = result.get_best_trial("loss", "min", "last")
    print("Best trial config: {}".format(best_trial.config))
    print("Best trial final validation loss: {}".format(
        best_trial.last_result["loss"]))
    print("Best trial final validation accuracy: {}".format(
        best_trial.last_result["accuracy"]))

    best_trained_model = Net(best_trial.config["l1"], best_trial.config["l2"])
    device = "cpu"
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = "cuda:0"
        if gpus_per_trial > 1:
            best_trained_model = nn.DataParallel(best_trained_model)
    best_trained_model.to(device)

    best_checkpoint_dir = best_trial.checkpoint.value
    model_state, optimizer_state = torch.load(os.path.join(
        best_checkpoint_dir, "checkpoint"))
    best_trained_model.load_state_dict(model_state)

    test_acc = test_accuracy(best_trained_model, device)
    print("Best trial test set accuracy: {}".format(test_acc))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # You can change the number of GPUs per trial here:
    main(num_samples=10, max_num_epochs=10, gpus_per_trial=0)
```

**The Feedback**

```sh
(ch36) ch@ICRC-Station:~/Ray$ python train.py
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 207, in <module>
    main(num_samples=10, max_num_epochs=10, gpus_per_trial=0)
  File "train.py", line 179, in main
    scheduler=scheduler)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 316, in run
    _ray_auto_init()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 754, in _ray_auto_init
    ray.init()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 912, in init
    ray_params=ray_params)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.start_head_processes()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 902, in start_head_processes
    self.start_redis()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 717, in start_redis
    port_denylist=self._ray_params.reserved_ports)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 942, in start_redis
    listen_to_localhost_only=(node_ip_address == "127.0.0.1"))
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 1097, in _start_redis_instance
    wait_for_redis_to_start("127.0.0.1", port, password=password)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 715, in wait_for_redis_to_start
    redis_client.client_list()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 399, in client_list
    return self.execute_command('CLIENT LIST', *args)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1068, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1173, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 567, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 613, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

Then I wait for a longer time shown as below:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 567, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 625, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 613, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 715, in wait_for_redis_to_start
    redis_client.client_list()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 399, in client_list
    return self.execute_command('CLIENT LIST', *args)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1068, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1173, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 571, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection timed out.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepCell_train_modify.py", line 803, in <module>
    progress_reporter=reporter)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 316, in run
    _ray_auto_init()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 754, in _ray_auto_init
    ray.init()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 912, in init
    ray_params=ray_params)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.start_head_processes()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 902, in start_head_processes
    self.start_redis()
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/node.py", line 717, in start_redis
    port_denylist=self._ray_params.reserved_ports)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 942, in start_redis
    listen_to_localhost_only=(node_ip_address == "127.0.0.1"))
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 1097, in _start_redis_instance
    wait_for_redis_to_start("127.0.0.1", port, password=password)
  File "/home/ch/anaconda3/envs/ch36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/_private/services.py", line 737, in wait_for_redis_to_start
    " attempts to ping the Redis server.") from connEx
RuntimeError: Unable to connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379 after 16 retries. Check that 127.0.0.1:6379 is reachable from this machine. If it is not, your firewall may be blocking this port. If the problem is a flaky connection, try setting the environment variable `RAY_START_REDIS_WAIT_RETRIES` to increase the number of attempts to ping the Redis server.
```

Clear that there is something wrong about network port.